# Convert hex to dec using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a large csv files , where few columns values are in hex. I need to convert them into decimal. The CSV files are very big. So If I process each row , then it takes a lot of time to execute the script. So I want to know how this can be done parallely by using awk command

If I process the code line by line it works.

I process the files like this.

```
while read -r line;
do
    start_time=`echo "$line"|awk -F "," '{ print $1 }'`
    end_time=`echo "$line"|awk -F "," '{ print $2 }'`
    st_time=$((16#$start_time))
    en_time=$((16#$end_time))
```

Then I echo the required fields to output file.

Sample Input file:

```
16a91f90539,16a91f931a9,e,0
16a91f90bab,16a91f931a9,e,0
```

Expected output:

```
1557227177273,1557227188649,e,0
1557227178923,1557227188649,e,0
```

I need to know how the statement `"((16#$start_time))"` , can be used in awk. 
I tried

```
awk -F',' '{OFS=",";}{print '"(($1#16))"','$en_time',$3'
```

But this syntax does not work.

Comment: Please do wrap your samples(codes) in code tags as it is not clear.

Comment: In the future, please use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on selected text to have the correct formatting ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for strtonum() you don't need to spawn multiple shells on each input line:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=1;i<=2;i++) $i=strtonum("0x"$i)} 1' file
1557227177273,1557227188649,e,0
1557227178923,1557227188649,e,0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute system calls from withnig awk with `system(...)`. Don't forget to close the command afterwards.

```
awk -F "," '{ cmd=sprintf("echo $((0x%s))\n", $1); system(cmd); close(cmd); }' input
```

(for some reason the system call does not work with `$((16#...))` on my system, but does work with `$((0x...))`)

With `getline` you can assign the echo'ed output to a variable. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline-Notes.html to get you started.

Comment: This command prints the output in next line. How can I print it with comma. Also there are multiple fields which needs this conversion. So each time do I need to open and close the cmd. For instance for printing 3 rows I tried like this "awk -F "," '{OFS=",";}{ cmd=sprintf("echo $((0x%s))\n", $1); system(cmd); close(cmd);  }{ cmd=sprintf("echo $((0x%s))\n", $2); system(cmd); close(cmd);  }{print $3}'". But this is printing all the values with new line

Comment: The return value from `system(foo)` is the exit status of `foo` so `foo` is already closed when `system()` returns. You can't use `system(foo)` to modify fields and include them in the output since `foo` will just print it's output to stderr independent of any `print`s in the awk script. The right way to modify `$1` using `cmd` is `foo="cmd \047"$1"\047"; $1=( (foo | getline line) > 0 ? line : "N/A"); close(foo)` but read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline before using that to make sure it's warranted and you understand the caveats.

Comment: I think @Ed Morton's solution is better for it avoids spawning the extra shells per input line, and avoids all the caveats of `system()` and `getline`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sprintf`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=1;i<=2;i++) $i=sprintf("%d", "0x"$i)} 1' file
2147483647,2147483647,e,0
2147483647,2147483647,e,0
```

Comment: `@aleb` : very much dependent on which `awk` you're using. Try running that with `gawk -e`  instead of `awk` (on your system i'm presuming that means the older `mawk-1` since the values got truncated down to `2^31 - 1`) and it'll give back 2 zeros

Answer (score 0):

no function calls needed :

```
echo '16a91f90539,16a91f931a9,e,0
      16a91f90bab,16a91f931a9,e,0' |
```

---

```
gawk -n '($1 = +("0x"$1))($2 = +("0x"$2))' FS=',' OFS=','
mawk     '$1 = +("0x"$+($2 =+("0x"$2))^_)' FS=,   OFS=,
```

---

```
1557227177273,1557227188649,e,0
1557227178923,1557227188649,e,0
```

- works on `mawk-1`, `nawk`, `gawk -n`, `gawk -nM`, or `gawk -P`

  —  but ***NOT*** on `gawk -MP`, `gawk -c`, `gawk -e`, or `mawk-2`

a single `regex` call would be like

---

```
nawk 'sub("^[^,]+,", "0x&0x")($1+=_)($2+=_)'
```

---

```
1557227177273,1557227188649,e,0
1557227178923,1557227188649,e,0
```

If the input's hex already has the `0x | 0X` prefix, then it's really really succinct :

```
echo 0x123456789ABCDEF010141010FEDCBA987654321 |
```

> ```
> gawk -nM '$_+=_'
> ```

```
6495562832581790663020768316961677305853592353 (a 152-bit prime)
```